Is there a way to know the exchange rates at Changi airports?
I am traveling to Singapore next week, and would like to know if it is better to buy SGD at home, or at the Changi airport, or somewhere else. Is there a way to know the current exchange rates that are given in the exchanges in the Changi airport?
I found this website, but it apparently shows exchange rates from 4 years ago.

Where is home and what currency do you want to exchange? If you want to exchange Israeli shekels, you will get a terrible rate for cash and are much better using an ATM.

As far as I can tell, the best rates at Changi are at ChangiFX, but they only quote SGD sell rates online: https://fx.changirecommends.com/

I suggest to avoid Changi and go to city and exchange. Exchanges at Mustafa and all provided good rates.

@lambshaanxy yes, the website is apparently aimed at Singaporeans flying abroad. I believe the rates in an ATM are better, but I fear that my credit card will not work for some reason, so I prefer to also have cash to exchange.

As a resident of Singapore, I might be qualified to answer this question.
If you are trying to exchange cash-for-cash, the airport is perhaps the most convenient, but there are many money changers in the city centre that will do cash-for-cash exchange at better rates.  One of the more competitive places to exchange money is in a small shopping mall known as The Arcade, directly above Raffles Place MRT Station, where there are more than a dozen money changers in operation (mostly on the second floor).  Each of them has a screen that shows their exchange rates, so you can walk the length of the mall before deciding on the one that will give you the best rate for your currency.
While some money changers will probably accept Israeli Shekels and other smaller currencies, the rate is likely to be worse than US Dollars (best) or Euros.  Unless you are intending to sell currency from a country from which many people work in Singapore or where many Singaporean tourists visit, you will likely be better off exchanging your home currency for US Dollars at home, and then exchanging US Dollars for Singapore Dollars in Singapore.

How often do you need cash these days? I thought Singapore was mostly cashless by now.

@Hilmar mostly cashless, but some of those cashless stores require a local bank account (PayNow). Majority will accept debit/credit card, but there are a few places where it's "cash or PayNow", which for tourists mean it's cash-only. If you're going shopping in shopping malls, of course you can go full cashless. But if you are exploring various local foods, having some cash would be good.

I've definitely encountered stores in malls that take only cash, PayNow, and possibly NETS, but no credit cards.  They aren't directly targeted at tourists though.  Hawker centres might not even accept NETS.
